# Hash of Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have one hash, where key is a string and value is an array of a string. 
I want something like this:

```
{"k1"=>["v1", "v2"], "k2"=>["v3", "v4"]}
```

I have only one hash and one array to implement this. I have coded something like this:

```
hash1 = Hash.new
arr = Array.new
arr.push "v1"
arr.push "v2"
hash1["k1"] = arr 

#hash is like this: {"k1"=>["v1", "v2"]
#Now I clear the array to read the new values

arr. clear
arr.push "v3"
arr.push "v4"
hash1["k2"] = arr
puts hash1

#Output: {"k1"=>["v3", "v4"], "k2"=>["v3", "v4"]}
#Notice that k1's value also got updated
```

Then I changed one line:

```
hash1 = Hash.new
arr = Array.new
arr.push "v1"
arr.push "v2"
hash1["k1"] = arr 

arr = [] # ** This is the only changed line.  Now k1's value is correct. **
arr.push "v3"
arr.push "v4"
hash1["k2"] = arr
puts hash1
#Output: {"k1"=>["v1", "v2"], "k2"=>["v3", "v4"]} (which I wanted)
```

Can someone please explain me how does this happen? I am very new to Ruby. Ideally, what is the correct way to code this problem?

Comment: "I have only one hash and one array to implement this." Not in your second example. There you have two arrays.

Comment: `{ }` is almost always preferable to `Hash.new`, and `[ ]` to `Array.new`.

Comment: @tadman why is it preferable?  Is it just for readability? or is there any other benefits?

Comment: @AnirudhanJ That notation is more concise and less prone to error. IT also makes it easy to add elements later, where `{ }` becomes `{ foo: 'bar' }` instead of having to switch from `Hash.new` to that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should show you what is happening ([`object_id`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id) is your friend). (I've inserted an underscore in the Object_id to make it easier to see differences.)

```
hash1 = {}            # => {} 
arr = ["v1", "v2"]    # => ["v1", "v2"] 
arr.object_id         # => 7016637_4343580 
hash1["k1"] = arr     # => ["v1", "v2"] 
hash1                 # => {"k1"=>["v1", "v2"]}
hash1["k1"].object_id # => 7016637_4343580 
arr.clear             # => [] 
arr.object_id         # => 7016637_4343580 
arr << "v3" << "v4"   # => ["v3", "v4"] 
arr.object_id         # => 7016637_4343580 
hash1["k2"] = arr     # => ["v3", "v4"] 
hash1                 # => {"k1"=>["v3", "v4"], "k2"=>["v3", "v4"]} 
hash1["k1"].object_id # => 7016637_4343580 
hash1["k2"].object_id # => 7016637_4166580 

arr = []              # => [] 
arr.object_id         # => 7016637_4036500 
arr = ["v5", "v6"]    # => ["v5", "v6"] 
arr.object_id         # => 7016637_3989880 
hash1                 # => {"k1"=>["v3", "v4"], "k2"=>["v3", "v4"]} 
hash1["k1"].object_id # => 7016637_4343580 
hash1["k2"] = arr     # => ["v5", "v6"] 
hash1                 # => {"k1"=>["v3", "v4"], "k2"=>["v5", "v6"]} 
hash1["k1"].object_id # => 7016637_4343580 
hash1["k2"].object_id # => 7016637_3989880
```

Comment: nice explanation.

if i want to sort my hash with value v1 or v2 how should i do?

`hash1.sort_by {|k,v| v.first}` #undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

`hash1.sort_by {|k,v| v[0]}` #undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Please leave another comment with an example of `hash1` and what you'd like the result of the hash to be.

Comment: consider an array of hashes like this 
`[{"a"=>[576, 236]},
 {"z"=>[348, 4859]},
 {"b"=>[174, 98]},
 {"t"=>[165, 145]},
 {"u"=>[97, 184]},
 {"m"=>[595, 374]},
 {"g"=>[61, 86]}]`

how should i sort my array of hashes using sum of values for each key?

like this 

`[{"z"=>[348, 4859]},
{"a"=>[576, 236]},
{"m"=>[595, 374]},
{"t"=>[165, 145]},
{"u"=>[97, 184]},
 {"b"=>[174, 98]},
 {"g"=>[61, 86]}]`

Comment: @h.APP.y  For sorting by largest sum first: `arr.sort_by { |h| -h.values.first.reduce(:+) }
`.

Comment: thanks for guidance.
Can you explain little more. i want to know how it worked.plz

Comment: I provided the requested explanation privately.

Answer (score 3):

The array you saved on the hash is still referenced with `arr` so clearly doing `arr.clear` and using `arr.push` would clean up and add new values to the one saved on the hash as well. However doing `arr = []`, `arr` would now reference a new array which is different from the one saved in hash.

And you can simply add a new array to hash with:

```
hash1["k2"] = ["v3", "v4"]
```

Or

```
hash1["k2"] = %w[v3 v4]
```

Comment: Adding to the answer so you can see it working, do this on your `arr`, `arr.object_id`, you'll receive a number, when you use `clear` and check again the id, it's the same (still same reference), when you `arr = []` you create a new object with the same name, overriding the old one, check it with `arr.object_id` and you'll have a different id number, which means, a new object :)